# how to improve mysql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Could you help me to make this query faster. My query is workable, but too slow :'(

I want to get all rows from my table, where value of coloumn `word` meets more than once.

My query looks like next:

```
select * from `t` 
where id in (select id from `t` group by word having count(*)>1)
```

Comment: In your sub-query, you group by `word`, but you return `id`.  If a value for `word` can have more than one `id` associated with it, which I would expect since I would expect `id` to be unique in that table, are you sure that you're getting the right results for that query?

Comment: select * from new where word in (select word from new group by word having count(*)>1) order by word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query should give you more accurate results... indexing `word` should improve your performance:

```
select t1.* 
from new as t1 
join (select word from new group by word having count(*) > 1) as t2
on t1.word = t2.word
```

Comment: !!!! THANKS !!!! This qurty brings the same result, but works 0,047 sec, instead of my 12 sec

Answer (score 0):

```
select new.* from new 
JOIN (select word from new group by word having count(*)>1) AS new1
USING (word)
```

Comment: select * from new where word in (select word from new group by word having count(*)>1) order by word

Comment: Why the `left join` it's not needed, nor is the `order by`. You're only increasing the work the DB has to do. Plus, you should really be using `on` not `using` as it's restricted to where the columns have the same name, which means you're not going to have consistent code.

Comment: @ben the new edited query which the OP posted in the comment has an order by. Also the using will work in this case since the column names will always be the same since the join is on the same table. You are right with the left join being not required

Comment: @ben thats fine. i removed the order by since the question doesn't order by now

Answer (score 0):

Adding indexes could speed your query (no details about how you created the table).

**FIXED** : ok, got it wrong, without subquery you can get the word appearing several time but not all the rows, while you indeed need exactly all the rows.